# How to use fmincon in a loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have 5 unknown parameters but only 4 equations, but each parameter has an interval, so I prefer to use `fmincon`. For example, these are 4 equations:

```
2*x(3) + x(5) + 5*x(1) - 1 = 0; 
7*x(4) + 3*x(3) + x(2) - 10 = 0; 
x(3) + 2*x(5) + 5*x(1) - 3 = 0; 
3*x(4) + 9*x(5) + x(2) - 10 = 0;
```

My idea is like this:

```
for x(1)=0.1:0.1:1
    fmincon(@myfun, x0,[]...);
end
```

But I do not know how to let `x(1)` be changed in the loop. Thank you for any suggestions in advance.

Comment: If `x(1)` to `x(5)` are your unknowns why are you changing them rather than letting `fmincon` do that? That's the whole point of optimization. What is your actual `myfun`, `x0` and call to `fmincon`? If your parameters are only defined over specific intervals then use the `LB` and `UB` input arguments. Perhaps you should re-read the documentation, try some of the examples, and come back and clarify your question.

Comment: @horchler Since there are only four equations but five parameters, so I think [fmincon] may not able to calculate them, and thus I want to fix one parameter first and then use [fmincon] to find values for other parameters, and so I use a loop. [myfun] are those equations that I mentioned above.

Comment: No, the equations above aren't code. This is a programming site, not a math site. You should post the code the function. `myfun` needs to return a scalar and you need to determine what you're minimizing. I think you may be using the wrong tool for the job but you haven't described your problem fully or shown much code (what does "each parameter has an interval" mean?). [`lsqlin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqlin.html) or [`lsqnonneg`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqnonneg.html) are probably closer to what you want - provided that a simple `A\b` doesn't suffice.

Comment: I think I have figured out this question. It is a problem how to use anonymous function in MATLAB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have figured out this question. It is a problem how to use an anonymous function in MATLAB. I just give a simple example, but note that some contents are not provided.

```
for p=1:10  
    i=i+1;
x(i,:) = fmincon(@(X) myfun(X,p), x0, [], [], [], [], ...
    [], [], [],  options);
end
```

In this case, I can loop value of p in my function while using `fmincon`.

Thank you all for many helpful suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are following the clearest strategy. You have a linear system. So, I think the easist solution is to apply a kind of GMM (Generalized Moment method) to estimate your parameters x(1)...X(5) [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_method_of_moments].

1) Define by g(i) your equation number i. So i =1,...,4.

2) Make the vector v=[g(1),g(2),g(3),g(4)]'.

3) Solve the optimization problem find x(1),...,x(5) that solves min v'v. [Basically you are minimize \sum g(i)^2]

In order to solve this, you can use the fmincon as you suggested (but there is no loop here) or you can solve analitically using KKT http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions (since the number of parameters is only five). Another less more computationaly costly solution is to do a grid over the possible values of X(i) in order min v'v, but this can last forever.

I hope I helped u

Comment: Can I put those equations in my script with {fmincon}, instead of writing a function to include my equations?

Comment: @Leo! Sure! You have to define g1=2*x(3) + x(5) + 5*x(1) - 1, ..., g4=3*x(4) + 9*x(5) + x(2) - 10 = 0; So define v above and return v'v!